# Как ограничить размер WebView в Java Android?

Tags: java, android, webview

Как ограничить размер WebView, чтобы ширина не увеличивалась при загрузке большой картинки или широкой страницы?

Comment: выставить ширину явно? выставить вес? XML в студию!

Comment: Пытался выставить ширину вот так:                                                                                 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);                                                                                      WebSettings ws  = wv.getSettings();    ws.(не нашел установки фиксированного размера)

Comment: У меня WebView на весь экран. Какой вес надо указать, чтобы не было увеличения?

Comment: если на весь экран, то его ширина и не увеличивается. Увеличивается ширина контента внутри него. Добавьте к изображению CSS, который ограничит его размер.    
И вообще, что это за извращение - показывать картинку через WebView?

Comment: Не, WebView я использую для загрузки страниц, просто попробовал картинку туда загрузить и увидел как его разнесло. Картинку внутри ограничить еще проще - задать размер внутри <img src...width="100"... Просто интересно было как по другому решить. Ну и если страницу из сети загрузить, то его тоже ограничить хотел. А оказывается это не его разносит, а содержимое. А во  внешнюю страницу я CSS не засуну.